# How to programmatically download GitHub data using C#

Tags: c#, github, download

The NY Times is maintaining a GitHub repository at https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data. This repository contains License, ReadMe, and two data files. The data files are us-states.csv and us-counties.csv. Both contain a time-series collection of the daily number of cases and deaths of COVID-19 by state or county.

I am trying to download the us-states.csv file. The program that I developed is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace NYTimes_Console
    {

    // ************************************************* class Program

    class Program
        {

        // ****************************************************** Main

        static void Main ( string [ ] args )
            {
            byte [ ] bytes; 
            string   url = 
                        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/" + 
                        "covid-19-data/blob/master/us-states.csv";
            //string   url = 
            //            "https://github.com/nytimes/" + 
            //            "covid-19-data/blob/master/us-states.csv";


            try
                {
                using ( WebClient client = new WebClient ( ) )
                    {
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Anything");
                    bytes = client.DownloadData ( url );
                    }
                Console.WriteLine ( "Download Successful" );
                }
            catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Download Failed\n{0}",
                                    ex.Message.ToString ( ) );
                }
            Console.Write ( "Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine ( );
            }

        } // class Program

    } // namespace NYTimes_Console
```

When the url is "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/blob/master/us-states.csv", I receive the following:

```
Download Failed
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

When I look into the exception, I find:

```
InnerException = {"Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream."}
```

When the url is "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/blob/master/us-states.csv", I receive the following:

```
Download Failed
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

and the InnerException is null.

I appear to misunderstand the GitHub repositories and access to them.

Comment: Code you should have seem to work perfectly fine - `(new WebClient() ).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv")`. Please stare at the page where you got url from "download" button a bit more... and possibly [edit] post with info why you believe the url you have should work.

Comment: In the `raw` link, the `blob` segment doesn't exist. Just remove that. The `github.com` https address works without problems (as usual), but it's quite less useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to solve it like this:

```
string url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv";
```